# Finding a $\delta$ corresponding to $\epsilon = 0.01$ for $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta

The answer I have is not aligning with that in the back of the book and I can't determine why. Here is my work thus far:
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - f(a)| &= |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{2}| \\
&< |\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2}||\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{2}|\\
&< |(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{2})| \\
&< |x-2|< \epsilon
\end{align*}

So $\delta=\epsilon=0.01$

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong?

Comment: There actually is something wrong (an inequality), but it's inconsequential for the main idea.

Comment: Because the book I am using says the delta should be something different. My proof is good and the book is incorrect?

Comment: You used $a$ in the first part and then you switched $a$ to $2$.  Make sure to correct this, because your argument work for $2$ but not for any $a$.

Comment: Yes a=2. My apologies as I forgot to add that in my original post.

Comment: The inequality I have should be less than or equal to? If it’s not that, then could you clarify?

Comment: If you expand the modulus into two inequalities, you get that $\delta < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{50} - \frac{1}{10000}$. But any smaller value for $\delta$, such as 0.01 or e.g. 0.00001, is still going to be valid.

Comment: Keep in mind the logic of $\epsilon,\delta$ proofs: the $\epsilon>0$ is given to you (presumably $\epsilon = 0.01$ was given to you?); your job is to **find** an appropriate $\delta$ (which, as said in other comments, is *not* unique).

Comment: @JamesBradley The second inequality is incorrect. You can write it as "less than or equal to", but it would be clearer to use an actual equality, because the numbers are equal.